# Errors in my Java program, y=mx+b with method

Tags: java

I tried to make a program in which the user inputs the values for variables m and b and then passes these variables to a method linear() which prints function "y=mx+b" using passed variables. PFB the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class line
{
    double m, b;

    public void liner(double m,double b)
    {
        System.out.print("y = " + m + "x + " + b);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the Slope");
        m = reader.nextInt();
        reader.close();
        System.out.print("What is the Y Intercept");
        b = reader.nextInt();
        reader.close();
        liner (m, b);
    }
}
```

On running the above program I am getting the following errors:

```
 /line.java:17: error: non-static variable m cannot be referenced from a static context
 m = reader.nextInt();
 ^
/line.java:20: error: non-static variable b cannot be referenced from a
static context
 b = reader.nextInt();
 ^
 /line.java:22: error: non-static variable m cannot be referenced from a
 static context
 liner (m , b);
        ^
 /line.java:22: error: non-static variable b cannot be referenced from a
 static context
 liner (m , b);
            ^
/line.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
liner (m , b);
^
symbol:   method liner(double,double)
location: class line
5 errors
```

Comment: Add an `import java.util.Scanner;` , and remove the `;` after `public void liner(double m,double b)` .

Comment: You put a semicolon after method's declaration. Remove it to fix the problem. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your variable declarations for `m` and `b` into the main method, and add a `static` modifier on the `liner` method.

The variables `m` and `b` are not in the scope of the `main` method, which makes them unable to be accessed. Read about scope here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Without the `static` modifier,the `liner` method is not yet created when it is called in the `main`, which is why you are receiving this error. Read about class members here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html